# nohup error no such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, nohup

I am trying to run a string of `nohup` commands to get server statistics.
However I get an error of *'No such file or directory'*. Note that the 3 `nohup` calls are embedded in a script which is executed through a `cron` job. And the first `nohup` works but the other 2 return an error. Ironically enough, when run on a different server, the script works fine.

- Commands

  ```
  nohup vmpstat -a -n 60 1000 > myvmstats
  ```
- (works)

  ```
  nohup mpstat -P ALL 1 1000 > mympstats
  ```
- (returns: nohup cannot run command `mpstat`: no such file or directory)

  ```
  nohup iostat -t -x 60 1000 >myiostats
  ```
- (returns: nohup cannot run command `iostat`: no such file or directory)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is mpstat or iostat an alias?  Can you run the commands yourself?

Comment: It's running into problems run under cron; are the 'missing' commands on the PATH when run by cron?

Comment: I can run the commands by myself. I basically have the same script on 2 different servers with the same settings.
I use the cron just to fireoff the script.
In fact I just tried running the script by itself and it is working.
I wonder if it has to do with running inside the cron>
Although it is pretty much the same for the other server and runs inside the cron

Comment: Add a command/line to the cron-run script that does: `env > /tmp/cron.job`.  Review whether the PATH there includes what you expect, and in particular, whether it includes the directory (directories) where each of the three programs is installed.  And do check that you run the programs you expect from the command line: `which vmpstat mpstat iostat`.  It is a reasonable guess that the two 'missing' commands are not in a directory on PATH when your script is run by `cron`.  And `cron` gives you a bare minimal environment; it is completely unlike `at` in that respect.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!!!
It turns out including the whole path to the mpstat installation worked. Although I find it weird that the same settings on the second server work without including the entire path.
In any case all is responding well now>
Thanks again\

Comment: In my case this answer by Michael Hampton pointed the direction in transitioning from daemon to nohup and the quotes around arguments: https://serverfault.com/questions/477686/nohup-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual problem with scripts that run from the command line and not when run by `cron` is 'environment'.  There are many questions on SO where this is exemplified, including:

- [Perl script works but not when via cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341324/perl-script-works-but-not-via-cron/4341351#4341351)
- [Why does my command line not run from cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780072/why-does-my-command-line-not-run-from-cron/780091#780091)
- [Bash script not executing in cron correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812425/bash-script-not-executing-in-cron-correctly/8812493#8812493)
- [How can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)

For debugging purposes, add a command/line to the cron-run script that does:

```
env > /tmp/cron.job
```

Review whether the PATH there includes what you expect, and in particular, whether it includes the directory (directories) where each of the three programs is installed. And do check that you run the programs you expect from the command line:

```
which vmpstat mpstat iostat
```

It is a reasonable guess that the two 'missing' commands are not in a directory on PATH when your script is run by `cron`. And `cron` gives you a bare minimal environment; it is completely unlike `at` in that respect.

See also:

- [Crontab and testing a command to be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028683/crontab-and-testing-a-command-to-be-executed/6028899#6028899)
- [How do I add pre-hook and post-hook scripts that run before all of my cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548595/how-do-i-add-pre-hook-and-post-hook-scripts-that-run-before-all-of-my-cron-jobs/9656386#9656386)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should give the relative/absolute path of you program

For example:

`nohup ./****.sh > /home/user/test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this trying to nohup a python script.

In case anyone has this situation and in case the abovementioned answer by jeremyxu (10 years ago) doesn't fix your issue, linux needs the full path of the python folder as well.

1. get the full path

> which -a python3

2. sudo access to pthon

> sudo nohup /usr/local/bin/python3.10 script.py