# nohup: failed to run command ‘java’: No such file or directory

Tags: java, shell

I want run java application though shell script.The below is my demo shell script.

`nohup java -cp .:$CLASSPATH com.xx.xx.App >> path/to/xx.log &`

but get this error:

`nohup: failed to run command ‘java’: No such file or directory`

someone can solve this question? thx!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193824/nohup-error-no-such-file-or-directory should be considered when encountering these type issues

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by add this line to my shell script.

`source ~/.bashrc`

This method is reload system environment. Then shell script can use *java* command.