# Perl script running correctly, but as a crontab it does not work

Tags: perl, cron, asterisk

I have a Perl script which inserts values in to a Mysql DB. Within the same script, I check a condition, and if successful,  go to the asterisk CLI and run the originate command.  When I run it in the terminal it's working properly.  When I set it as a crontab, it will update the DB but the originate command is not working.  I am new to Perl, please help me to solve this.  Thanks in advance.

Perl script:

```
if($temperature > 85){
    print `asterisk -rx "originate Dongle/dongle0/0123456789 extension 400\@out"`;
}
```

Crontab:

```
*/1 * * * *   /home/test/bin/insert_mysql.pl
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028683/crontab-and-testing-a-command-to-be-executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cron** have different environment: he dont have PATH environment variable, so you must always use full path to commands; And, current directory is generally undefined, so when opening files must be careful; Also, it does not have locale settings but i think its not your case.

So you must give full path to `asterisk` and to file `Dongle/dongle0/0123456789` (if it is file)

Comment: when i type asterisk in su mode CLI will appear. then the originate command. so how can i get the full path ?